# R extracting the last row values of each factor in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one column containing factors in a sequence of variable lengths and other columns containing values. How can I extract just the last row values for each factor?

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","e","f","f","f","f","g","g"),y=c(diffinv(rnorm(20))),z=c(diffinv(rnorm(20))))
df
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Another option in base R would be: `df[!duplicated(df$x, fromLast = TRUE),]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous alternatives. This is not the most efficient, but it doesn't need a package:

```
aggregate(. ~ x, df, tail, n = 1)
```

Comment: An alternative from `dplyr` is  `df %>% group_by(x) %>% slice(n())` or a more compact one `setDT(df)[,.SD[.N],  x]` from `data.table`

Comment: I have a problem with aggregate when a column contains dates.The output dates are all wrongly formatted. How am I able to correct this?